# OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)) in cvRead

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I have trained haarclassifier and tried to find the width and height of the pattern which I am searching for, with the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


pattern_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('stage15.xml')


img = cv2.imread('image.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

pattern = pattern_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
(x,y,w,h) = pattern
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I am getting the following error. Can somebody help me in fixing this ?

```
kathir@kathir-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Haarcascade /neg and bg$ python FindPattern.py 
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)) in cvRead, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 4991
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FindPattern.py", line 5, in <module>
    pattern_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('stage15.xml')
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:4991: error: (-2) The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?) in function cvRead
```

If someone help to understand the error also, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you train your cascade using `opencv_traincascade`, the number of stages you want to train your model is the number of `xml` files it will generate for each stage. In the folder where you've stored all the xml files will look something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgNHH.png), there exists a file named `cascade.xml` which contains the data for all stages collectively. This `cascade.xml` is the file you've to use for CascadeClassifier, not any particular stage file.
Your code would look something like this.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


pattern_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')


img = cv2.imread('image.png')
....
```

Comment: Yeah I have used Cascade.xml. Still it is not loading

Comment: Try to copy the XML file in the same directory and continue.